# Make a .sis file (Symbian S60 3rd edition) from python(v2.6) script.

Tags: python, mobile, symbian, s60

I'm new to mobile programming and I would like to make a mobile app for symbian in python. I read that for S60 3rd edition I should use ensymble but the thing is that I'm using Python v2.6 and it seems that it isn't yet supported in ensymble. Does anyone know of other software and maybe some tutorials??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

well you should start with these:

http://www.samontab.com/web/2011/06/create-installable-applications-sis-files-from-your-python-scripts-for-symbian/

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/PyS60_1.4.5_Quick_Start

book: **Mobile Python Rapid Prototyping of Applications on the Mobile Platform**

this book is the best tutorial.. i started just yesterday, and i'm already having fun.
everything is instructed in simple steps, and its all easy

if you know python, you are a winner then in that case.
I on the other hand, am just starting out with python and python apps for my s60 3rd smartphone